# "there is no package called 'xlsx'": having trouble reading .xlsx file

Tags: r

Looking to read in an .xlsx file.  This is an assignment so I specifically can't use Excel first to convert it to .csv.

Tried using read.xlsx which couldn't be found so I tried 'library(xlsx)' which was not a package according to R.

Does anyone know if there's something glaringly obvious that I'm not doing?  Is the package called something different?  Is there a different/better way to read an xlsx file?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to install it (if you have rights) `install.packages("xlsx", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: did you make sure to install package first before loading it? `install.packages("xlsx")`

Comment: I honestly recommend first exporting your Excel data to a more easily manageable format (say, CSV), and only then opening it with R (with `read.csv()`, as usual). You don't need Excel to do this, LibreOffice Calc will do just fine.